# how to substring a string containing multiple strings

Tags: java, json, string, java-8

I have a string object which contains multiple strings..I want to extract the part after **"_json":** till it reaches **}**
But when I give this in my code , it is telling index out of bound exception.
Can anybody help to extract that part
The string which I am getting is

```
===Username===>>{"profile":{"id":"xxxxxx","name":{},"_raw":"{\"sub\":\"xxxxx\",\"country\":\"US\",\"firstname\":\"xxxx\",\"employeetype\":\"XXXX\",\"mail\":\"abc@yz.com\",\"gehrbusinesssegment\":\"avav\",\"gessobusinessunit\":\"AVI DT-xxxxx Engineering\",\"gessouid\":\"C2B0A5EB-8A20-170F-BF3E-002128B20D70\",\"cn\":\"Saha, Romit\",\"title\":\"Project Manager  (Backend)\",\"georaclehrid\":\"xxxxx\",\"lastname\":\"Saha\",\"uid\":\"xxxxx\",\"groupNAME\":[\"@GE AWS_bu-readonly_175070699551\",\"@GE AWS_bu-readonly_639624358806\",\"@AVIATION MRO Fulfillment Operations Advisor\",\"@POWER pge_role_super_user_dev\",\"@AVIATION DISE Friends of the Family\",\"@AVIATION MOA Users - Editor Access\",\"@AVIATION MOA-Viewer-Users\",\"@Gas Power Smartshop Users\",\"@AVIATION US VPN GROUP\",\"@Digital Emergency Change Notification 23\"],\"gessocompanyname\":\"XXXXXX\",\"gehrindustrygroup\":\"XXXXXX\",\"gessojobfunction\":\"Information Technology\",\"street\":\"XXXXXPlaza\",\"location\":\"XXXX\",\"state\":\"XXX\",\"geECIndicator\":\"N\"}\r\n","_json":{"sub":"XXXX","country":"US","firstname":"Romit","employeetype":"XXX","mail":"XXX@ge.com","gehrbusinesssegment":"XXX","gessobusinessunit":"AVI DT-Data Infrastructure & Software Engineering","gessouid":"C2B0A5EB-8A20-170F-BF3E-002128B20D70","cn":"Saha, Romit","title":"XXXXXX(Backend)","georaclehrid":"XXXX","lastname":"Saha","uid":"502622018","groupNAME":["@GE AWS_bu-readonly_175070699551","@GE AWS_bu-readonly_639624358806","@AVIATION MRO Fulfillment Operations Advisor","@POWER pge_role_super_user_dev","@AVIATION DISE Friends of the Family","@AVIATION MOA Users - Editor Access","@AVIATION MOA-Viewer-Users","@Gas Power Smartshop Users","@AVIATION US VPN GROUP","@Digital Emergency Change Notification 23"],"gessocompanyname":"XXXXX","gehrindustrygroup":"GE Aviation","gessojobfunction":"Information Technology","street":"XXXXX Plaza","location":"XXXX","state":"XXX","geECIndicator":"N"}},"accessTokenExp":1627090679000,"accessToken":"XXXXX","refreshTokenExp":1627105079000,"refreshToken":"XXXXX","user_info":{"family_name":"Saha","given_name":"Romit","user_name":"XXXXX"}}
```

But when I give this in my code, it is giving the exception

```
String json = username.substring(username.indexOf("_json") + 1, username.indexOf('}'));
```

Error:

```
2021-07-23 20:37:42 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/moa/api/v1] threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1137
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at com.ge.digital.oa.common.config.cloud.oidc.OIDCRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(OIDCRequestFilter.java:80) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as input string has multiple `}`, the being index and end index of substring is out of range

your current begin index: `1189`
end index `53` which results in `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:`

change `username.indexOf("}")` to `username.lastIndexOf("}")`

you can try to get lastIndex of '}'

```
         int begin = username.indexOf("_json") +1;
         int end = username.lastIndexOf("}");
         System.out.println("begin:"+begin+" end:"+end );
         String json = username.substring(begin, end);
         System.out.println(" jsonString: "+json);
```

Output:

```
jsonString: json":{"sub":"502622018","country":"US","firstname":"Romit","employeetype":"Contractor","mail":"romit.saha@ge.com","gehrbusinesssegment":"Aviation Digital Technology","gessobusinessunit":"AVI DT-Data Infrastructure & Software Engineering","gessouid":"C2B0A5EB-8A20-170F-BF3E-002128B20D70","cn":"Saha, Romit","title":"Predix Senior Engineer (Backend)","georaclehrid":"502622018","lastname":"Saha","uid":"502622018","groupNAME":["@GE AWS_bu-readonly_175070699551","@GE AWS_bu-readonly_639624358806","@AVIATION MRO Fulfillment Operations Advisor","@POWER pge_role_super_user_dev","@AVIATION DISE Friends of the Family","@AVIATION MOA Users - Editor Access","@AVIATION MOA-Viewer-Users","@Gas Power Smartshop Users","@AVIATION US VPN GROUP","@Digital Emergency Change Notification 23"],"gessocompanyname":"General Electric Company","gehrindustrygroup":"GE Aviation","gessojobfunction":"Information Technology","street":"3200 Windy Hill Road, The Towers at Wildwood Plaza","location":"Atlanta","state":"GA","geECIndicator":"N"}},"accessTokenExp":1627090679000,"accessToken":"0003Kpc7Av3noCCKZrKpcSgPnRb2","refreshTokenExp":1627105079000,"refreshToken":"v4Qx3JcAd99zmZnd5WgvYJw83KHBUkAbnb9Ogn02jS","user_info":{"family_name":"Saha","given_name":"Romit","user_name":"502622018"}
```

**Update:**

i would recommend using ObjectMapper to convert jsonstring to POJO and access values from object

convert json string to pojo using tools

passing userName json string to below code will map json string to java object `Root`
you can access required data from respective members
Here `root.getProfile().get_json()` will get you `_json`

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(userName), Root.class);
```

your pojos are as below

```
public class Name{
}


public class Json{
    public String sub;
    public String country;
    public String firstname;
    public String employeetype;
    public String mail;
    public String gehrbusinesssegment;
    public String gessobusinessunit;
    public String gessouid;
    public String cn;
    public String title;
    public String georaclehrid;
    public String lastname;
    public String uid;
    public List<String> groupNAME;
    public String gessocompanyname;
    public String gehrindustrygroup;
    public String gessojobfunction;
    public String street;
    public String location;
    public String state;
    public String geECIndicator;
}

public class Profile{
    public String id;
    public Name name;
    public String _raw;
    public Json _json;
}

public class UserInfo{
    public String family_name;
    public String given_name;
    public String user_name;
}

public class Root{
    public Profile profile;
    public long accessTokenExp;
    public String accessToken;
    public long refreshTokenExp;
    public String refreshToken;
    public UserInfo user_info;
}
```

another suggestion is you can mask private data before posting question

Comment: yeah...that is correct..it prints the rest of the string after }}..need to find some trick

Comment: i was able to achieve my obejctive by modifying the above code -String jsonmiddle = username.substring(begin, end);
          String jsonfinal = jsonmiddle.substring(jsonmiddle.indexOf("{"),jsonmiddle.indexOf("}")+1);

Answer (score 0):

You can extract that value using `simple-json` library like this:

```
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(yourJsonString); 
    
        String _json= (String) jobj.get("_json"); // Extract the value from your key
    
        System.out.println(_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you say `username.indexOf('}')`, it is taking the first '}', which is before the '_json' index in the username string. This gives a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the end index (second parameter of the `substring` method) needs to be after the start index (first parameter of the `substring` method).

What you instead have to do is `username.split('_json')`, then call `username.indexOf('}')` on the second half of the result from the split call to get the index of the first '}' character after the '_json'. Then you can just do `username.substring(username.indexOf("_json") + 1, /*insert the index of the '}' character you found earlier here */)`.